# Selling OS Software

Tags: business

We are a startup building a desktop application using Python 
targeting schools. Morally we want to Open up the source. But we are concerned how we will restrict others downloading for free there by impacting our business. Conventional business strategies of looking other avenues of revenue like support seems limited. Any ideas how we may go open source but still be able to protect the business?

Comment: If you don't want people to download your code, what benefit do you expect to get by opening it up?

Comment: Sorry, that I didn't mean just downloading, but redistributing it and creating a business of it. At the same time I like to share code with my buyers under no redistribution clause, but free to do any modification for their own usage.

Comment: @user4579 When that's what you want, then get a lawyer to write a license agreement which allows the licensee to view and modify the sourcecode, but not to distribute it. But please don't call it open source.

Comment: Is it a learning software? Then you could open source the software itself but sell the content.

Comment: @Phillip That's a great idea to sell content. It seems to be a good idea to implement.

Comment: You could get an open source Licence. https://opensource.org/licenses. You maintain the intellectual rights.